# Save variable in existing .txt file in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i want to save the value of a variable into a existing .txt file. But when i run the file, the program generates a new .txt file everytime i press save..

Please help me..

here is my code so far.

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba.writeUTFBytes(total_text.text);

        file.save( ba, "register.txt" );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save a variables value into a existing .txt file with actionscript 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567787/save-a-variables-value-into-a-existing-txt-file-with-actionscript-3)

Comment: Definite duplicate; that was asked by the same user merely an hour later.